# Error in default API testing | V1/carts/mine/shipping-information

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, rest-api, shipping-address, billing-address

I just wanted to test [this](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/rest/tutorials/orders/order-prepare-checkout.html#set-addresses) API for understanding order flow

```
{  "addressInformation": {
      "shipping_address": {
       "region": "New York",
       "region_id": 43,
       "region_code": "NY",
       "country_id": "US",
       "street": [
      "123 Oak Ave"
    ],
    "postcode": "10577",
    "city": "Purchase",
    "firstname": "Jane",
    "lastname": "Doe",
    "email": "jdoe@example.com",
    "telephone": "512-555-1111"
  },
  "billing_address": {
    "region": "New York",
    "region_id": 43,
    "region_code": "NY",
    "country_id": "US",
    "street": [
      "123 Oak Ave"
    ],
    "postcode": "10577",
    "city": "Purchase",
    "firstname": "Jane",
    "lastname": "Doe",
    "email": "jdoe@example.com",
    "telephone": "512-555-1111"
  },
  "shipping_carrier_code": "tablerate",
  "shipping_method_code": "bestway"
  }
}
```

but with above payload given in devdocs it show error:

> "message": "Carrier with such method not found: %1, %2",
> "parameters": [
> "tablerate",
> "bestway"   ],

how can it be tested?

Comment: Try to add this shipping method in your methods from admin page

Comment: Check the entire Guest Order flow, https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/guest-customer-place-an-order-by-rest-api-magento-2/

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to check available shipping methods by making this call:

```
POST /rest/default/V1/carts/mine/estimate-shipping-methods
```

with the following body (example):

```
{
"address": {
    "country_id": "PL",
    "street": [
      "..."
    ],
    "postcode": "...",
    "city": "..."
  }    
}
```

Don't forget to add a header:

```
Authorization: Bearer [customer token]
```

And sample response:

```
[
  {
    "carrier_code": "flatrate",
    "method_code": "flatrate",
    "carrier_title": "Flat Rate",
    "method_title": "Fixed",
    "amount": 50,
    "base_amount": 50,
    "available": true,
    "error_message": "",
    "price_excl_tax": 50,
    "price_incl_tax": 50
  }
]
```

Then you have to just put **method_code** and **carrier_code**

Full flow:

1. Get customer token POST /rest/default/V1/integration/customer/token
2. Create shopping-cart POST /rest/default/V1/carts/mine
3. Add item to shopping-cart POST /rest/default/V1/carts/mine/items
4. Get shipping information
5. Set up shipping
6. Set up a payment method

PS. I've stuck on setting up payments